# am try to rum npm start on my react native terninal it is not working it is showing me thos error

Tags: npm-start

PS C:\Users\solom\OneDrive\Desktop\react_native_jobs> npm start
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\solom\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-16T00_51_22_060Z-debug-0.log

i did npm start it is not working